# Background image and mouse out zoom problem

Tags: jquery, css

Got a small issue here I am trying to find a solution to.  Have a container called banner with a background image and some text. I am trying to get the image to zoom in when I hover the mouse over it (works) and slowly zoom back to 100% when the mouse leaves (not working).
The main issue here is that I don't know what the current background-size is when the mouse leaves. Any suggestions to how I can complete this code to get it working?

CSS:

```
.banner.out {
   animation-name: out;
   animation-duration:2s;
}

.banner.over {
   animation-name: in;
   animation-duration:5s;
   animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

@keyframes in {
    0% {
       background-size: 100%; 
    }
    100% {
       background-size: 120%; 
    }
}

@keyframes out {
  0% {
        background-size: 120%;
    }
    100% {
       background-size: 100%; 
    }
}
```

JQUERY:

```
$(".banner").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

why don't you use the transform: scale property for it and ad an transition for smoothness?
I think its easier when you want to zoom in and out of the picture like in the example below:

this is the normal state:
[image]

and when I hover over my picture this happens
[image]

I have added some blur for me but this is not important for you. the image is zooming in.
here is the code for it:

```css
&__img {
        height: 100%;
        transform: translateX(-3.5rem) scale(1.4);
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        transition: all 0.5s;
    }
    
    
    
  &:hover &__img {
        transform: translateX(-3.5rem) scale(1);
        filter: blur(3px) brightness(80%);
    }
```

Comment: Tried scale, but it also scales the text on the banner div. And I can't change the div as it's a premade widget.. I know it's not possible to get "current background-size" through css.. but maybe some other way around it to get it working.

Comment: Ooh ok, you haven't mentioned that this is a premade widget. this changes everything.